# Does ReflectionTestUtils works only on fields of a class, not on variables defined inside a method of that class?

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-test

Does ReflectionTestUtils works only on fields of a class, not on variables defined inside a method of that class?

I tried to test the fields of a class, it works perfectly fine using `ReflectionTestUtils`, if I try it on variables of a method, I get an `IllegalArgumentException`.

Example Code:

```
public class Check {
     String city;

     public void method() {
         city = "Bangalore";
         String Street = "MGRoad";
    }
}
```

If I want to have a JUnit tests for the above class using `ReflectionTestUtils`.

```
Check c = new Check();
assert ReflectionTestUtils.getField(c, "city").equals("Bangalore") 
-> works fine.
assert ReflectionTestUtils.getField(c, "Street").equals("MGRoad") 
-> gives illegalArgumentException.
```

Please have a look and suggest me if I can test the attributes of a method.

Comment: When they are defined inside a method, they are called "variables" and are not "fields".

Comment: In general, though, I would strongly advise against using things like `ReflectionTestUtils`, as it encourages you to test the wrong thing.  You should really be testing observable behaviour, not specific implementation details.  Otherwise, these tests become an impediment to later maintenance, rather than a help.

Comment: `String Street = "MGRoad";` this local variable to that method

Comment: yes, sorry for my mistake,i am new to java and spring boot,  wanted to test my service class, which calls MQ and saves the specific response details to the database `Address.setStreet(Street);` (uses jsonfile), i used mockito to mock the MQ. _I wanted a way to test the local variables_

Comment: It looks like the code you are trying to unit test requires refactoring to improve its design.

Comment: first of all why do you need to test local variable? those are specific to one thread only and any changes to local variables will be reflected in that method only @anushaMR

Answer (score 4):

You cannot access local variables using reflection and `String Street = "MGRoad";` is local variable to that method

> If what you mean is variables local to methods/constructors, you can not access them with reflection. ... There is no way to obtain this information via reflection. **Reflection works on method level, while local variables are on code block level.**